# Existe alguma forma de manter o usuário logado em um webapp

Tags: android, aplicação-web, rest, webview

Gostaria de saber se é possível manter um usuário logado com webapp utilizando de webview.
 Se sim qual séria a maneira correta.

Comment: Com webview trabalho somente para android e ios e os dois suportam `LocalSorage`, e é ai no [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) que eu armazeno se esta logado ou não. Para outras plataformas como WindowsPhone, Blackberry etc, não sei te dizer.

Comment: para aplicação web o melhor seria vc usar o cordova: https://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: realmente a ideia do localstorage é muito boa vou ver oque consigo fazer muito obrigado @NeuberOliveira

Comment: em questão do phonegap, estou começando a utilizar, mas o projeto a qual estou trabalhando está praticamente pronto de uma forma para webview, por isso que precisaria da solução no webview neste caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tenho um sistema todo na webview e utilizo controle atraves de cookies. 
procure informações sobre Setcookie ou Sessions